# How to specify the path when saving a QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, savefiledialog, qpixmap

In my program I generate a QPixmap using the grabWindow method. Then I'd like to save it using the Save File Dialog, so the user can choose the name and the path where it's going to be saved. I've tried the following without success:

```
def Save_Data(self):
    p = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(self.tabWidget_3.winId(), 0, 0, 691, 260)
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', '*.jpg')
    file = open(fileName, 'w')
    p.save(file, "PNG")
```

I've read in other posts that people usually convert the QPixmap into a QBuffer before saving it, but I've tried without any success either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Kind regards,

Comment: Just use `p.save(fileName, "PNG")`.  There's no need to open the file explicitly.

Comment: Worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[QtGui.QPixmap.save()](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtgui/qpixmap.html?highlight=qtgui%20qpixmap%20save) function recieves str. You can try this.

```
def Save_Data(self):
    p = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(self.tabWidget_3.winId(), 0, 0, 691, 260)
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', '*.jpg')
    p.save(fileName)
```

Comment: Tip: "try" implies you're not sure if proposed solution works at all. If it works on your system then it works and state it as such. If OP has problem running the code he/she will let you know via comment. Then you pick it up from there. End of Review.